# Passing column to external ajax call

Tags: php, jqgrid

I am using a custom_func to validate a field in the edit and add for form editing.  This custom_func is making an ajax call to the server to validate account numbers.  The problem is that the column is not being POSTed to the php.

JQUERY FUNCTION:

```
function chkAcct(value,colname){
    // var result = null;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'functions.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {action: 'chkAcct'},
        // dataType: 'xml',
        // contentType: 'application/xml; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(response){                
        if(response){
            result = [true,""];                 
        }
        else{
           result = [false,"This account already exists"];
        }
        alert(response);
        },          
        });
    return result;
}
```

PHP FUNCTION:

```
function chkAcct($conn){
    $sql = "SELECT dist_id FROM batch WHERE open_flg = '1'";
    $query = pg_query($conn,$sql);
    $row = pg_fetch_row($query);
    $dist = distConversion($row[0]);
    $cntrct_id = $dist.$_POST['cntrct_id'];

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM addru ad, cntrt ct WHERE ct.cntrct_id = '$cntrct_id' AND ad.cntrct_seq = ct.cntrct_seq AND ad.active_flg = '1'";   
    $query = pg_query($conn,$sql);
    $row = pg_fetch_row($query);
    $count1 = $row[0];

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM nmaddr nm WHERE nm.cntrct_id = '$cntrct_id'";
    $query = pg_query($conn,$sql);
    $row = pg_fetch_row($query);
    $count2 = $row[0];
    $total = $count1+$count2;

    if($total === 0){
        $myfile = "text.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myfile,'a');
        fwrite($fh,$total);
        fclose($fh);
        echo $cntrct_id;
     }
  }
```

AND, finally, the row in question:

```
    { name:'cntrct_id',
        editoptions:{ maxlength:8 }, 
        editrules:{
            custom:true, 
            custom_func: chkAcct,
        }  
    },
```

I tried using data:{ cntrct_id: 'cntrct_id' } in the editoptions of the row to manually send the value of the column to the server, but to no avail.  What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't posting the `cntrct_id` field, you are only posting `chkAcct`.

You need to POST the contract field by adding it to the data object:

```
data: {
  action: 'chkAcct',
  cntrct_id: $('#cntrct_id').val()
}
```

Replace `$('#cntrct_id')` with the correct reference to the data.

Comment: mcryan, your solution has solved my problem.  I must add that the column must be referenced as $('#cntrct_id').val(), because $('#cntrct_id') breaks the grid.  I will accept as answer as soon as SO will allow.

Comment: Great. I've added `.val()` to my answer.